# How To Select Value From Modal PopUp In Katalon Studio?

Tags: katalon-studio

I am trying to automate the registration page by recording with Katalon studio and try to read data from excel but value selection from the modal popup is not working. I have attached the 2 images. Can anyone please help me with how to select the value from modal popup?

Comment: Where are the attached images?

Comment: Thanks for your concern. There may be some mistakes. Also, I have solved the issue already. Once again thanks.